# How create Makeself self executable archive file in LINUX? What is the steps to create Makeself self executable file in any Operating System?

Tags: linux, bash, compression, archiving, self-extracting

I want to create a self-executable archive using Makeself.
I referred to **[makeself.io](https://makeself.io/)** but didn't understand anything from it.
What are the steps for making a Makeself self-executable archive?

If I run this executable on any operating system then it should be work and do my required task.